# Query arrays of data

Tags: java, mysql, sql, arrays

How can I query data from my database and assign it to an array of strings? In this attempt I noticed I would receive an out of bounds error before I included the `resultSet.next()` call since it seems that `ResultSet` starts at 0 and is not called like a list / array (meaning you can access the contents with its index).

```
public String[][] retrieveNameAndLocation() {
    final String table = "customers";

    try {
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(
                "SELECT " +
                    "first_name," +
                    "location" +
                " FROM " + table
        );

        resultSet.next();
        final String[] names = (String[]) (resultSet.getArray(1).getArray());
        final String[] location = (String[]) (resultSet.getArray(2)).getArray();
        final String[][] nameAndCountry = {names, location};

        resultSet.close();
        return nameAndCountry;
    } catch (SQLException  e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Anyways the above code resulted in a `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`. My next attempt was to simply call the the columns by name since I noticed it was an option inside of `getArray`, however that also resulted in the not supported exception.

```
public String[][] retrieveNameAndLocation() {
    final String table = "customers";

    try {
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(
                "SELECT " +
                    "first_name," +
                    "location" +
                " FROM " + table
        );

        resultSet.next();
        final String[] names = (String[]) (resultSet.getArray("first_name").getArray());
        final String[] location = (String[]) (resultSet.getArray("location")).getArray();
        final String[][] nameAndCountry = {names, location};

        resultSet.close();
        return nameAndCountry;
    } catch (SQLException  e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am not really sure why I need to include `resultSet.next()` because it seems like it's just broken since why would they include an option to query columns if they forced you to loop through the indexes?

Comment: `next()` is used to navigate the records, as the docs say: `The next method moves the cursor to the next row, and because it returns false when there are no more rows in the ResultSet object, it can be used in a while loop to iterate through the result set.`, surely there's more than one record in the table? ... and to the `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` happens when: `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException - if the JDBC driver does not support this method`.

Comment: @PaulT. I have 4 columns and I have printed the complete tables by looping so I know its all set up correctly. The exception occurs on the getArray() line but why would this not be supported?

Comment: I do not know. An older driver, perhaps? What driver is being used.

Comment: @PaulT. How would I check that everything I have is recent. That method has been around for many years (based upon me googling this question) so I have no idea how its not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the purpose of method [getArray](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getArray(int)). Some DBMSs, like Oracle, have ["array" data types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adobj/support-for-collection-data-types.html#GUID-0EF7C6B0-B68A-4671-A7B6-857D8F6F3DA8). Hence the `getArray` method – to query a database table column whose type is an array type. I have no experience with MySQL but it appears that [it does not have an array type](https://sebhastian.com/mysql-array/). Hence the JDBC driver for MySQL does not need to implement the `getArray` method and that's why you get the `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`.

You need to iterate through the `ResultSet` and build up your array. However since you usually don't know how many rows there are in a `ResultSet`, I usually use a `List` and then, if required, convert it to an array because when you declare an array you need to know its size.

I would also define a [record](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/language/records.html) and declare a `List` of records.
(Note that below code is not compiled and not tested since I don't have your database and I can't simulate it since the code in your question is not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).)

```java
public record NameAndCountry(String name, String location) {
    public static java.util.List<NameAndCountry> retrieveNameAndLocation() {
        final String table = "customers";
        try {
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(
                "SELECT " +
                    "first_name," +
                    "location" +
                " FROM " + table
            );
            java.util.List<NameAndCountry> list = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                String name = resultSet.getString(1);
                String location = resultSet.getString(2);
                NameAndCountry row = new NameAndCountry(name, location);
                list.add(row);
            }
        } catch (SQLException  e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```